# How to use RMagic in jupyter for console text output

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2

I'm using jupyter with RMagic cells for the R language. It works fine, except that simple R console output does not appear in the notebook, whereas plots work as expected. The shell from which the notebook was started shows the missing output.

e.g. The python cell looks as follows:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
import numpy as np





Xp=np.array([-1,-2,-3,-4,-5])
Yp=1./Xp
print("\n Xp=",Xp,"   Yp=",Yp)
```

Output is as expected:

Xp= [-1 -2 -3 -4 -5]    Yp= [-1.         -0.5        -0.33333333 -0.25       -0.2       ]

followed by a simple R cell

```
%%R -i Xp -i Yp -o Zr

Zr<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
yr=1./Xp+Zr
plot(Xp,yr)
```

which works fine too, getting the expected plot
[image]

and finally the next R cell

```
%%R
Y <- c(2,4,3,9)
X <- c(1,4,5,7) 
print(Y)
mean(X)
```

The last cell does not show any result in the notebook, however the result can be found in the shell jupyter was started from.

I'm using Python 3.7.4, notebook server 6.0.1 IPython 7.8.0, R 3.6.1, rpy2 2.9.4 windows 10 with anaconda.

The solution proposed in
https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023857294-R-Magic-in-Windows-and-Jupyter-Notebook-Output-Issue-
does not work for me.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I tried, as suggested, an update to a newer version with

```
pip install rpy2-3.4.2.tar.gz
```

with the meassage: Successfully installed rpy2-3.4.2

Unfortunately the R.dll does not load anymore, even though the given path name in the error message contains the R.dll.

Running the simple script

```
import os
os.environ["R_HOME"] = "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\MyApps\\anaconda3\\Lib\\R\\"
#set R bin
os.environ['path'] += r';C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\MyApps\\anaconda3\\Lib\\R\\bin;' 

import rpy2.robjects as robjects

print("Hello")
```

works fine in a script, but not in the jupyter notebook. Again the same error message:

```
.........
.........
~\MyApps\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\openrlib.py in _dlopen_rlib(r_home)
     35         raise ValueError('The library path cannot be None.')
     36     else:
---> 37         rlib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)
     38     return rlib
     39 

OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Lib\R\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e
```

comes up as with the original jupyter notebook when processing the line
%load_ext rpy2.ipython

Using a R jupyter notebook works fine, so no issues with the path there.

Thanks for ideas

**SOLVED**

Adding the following pathes to the PATH variable

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Lib\R\bin

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\lib

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin

and defining the R_HOME variable as

C:\Users\xxxxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Lib\R

solved the problems with the R.dll

The original problem concerning the missing output is now solved too (with the newer version 3.4.2 of rpy2)

Comment: Maybe updating to a newer rpy2 version cold help?

Comment: Thanks. The newer versions are for mac or unix, 2.9.5 is the maximum I can get for windows a far as I understood,

Comment: I believe it is possible to manually install the new version on Windows too, but it is indeed a bit of a hassle. I would love to be able to help with it but don't have Windows myself

Comment: So I tried to install the newest version with pip install rpy2-3.4.2.tar.gz, which did not show up any problems. The older version was detected and uninstalled. However, there is now some trouble in the first python cell above with the R.dll.The error message is: OS Error: cannot load library 'C:\Users\xxxxx\MyApps\anaconda3\Lib\R\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0x7e , although the R.dll is there.